# How do I implement `cat` in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, conduit

I am trying to write a simple `cat` program in Haskell. I would like to take multiple filenames as arguments, and write each file sequentially to **STDOUT**, but my program only prints one file and exits.

What do I need to do to make my code print every file, not just the first one passed in?

```
import Control.Monad as Monad
import System.Exit
import System.IO as IO
import System.Environment as Env

main :: IO ()
main = do
    -- Get the command line arguments
    args <- Env.getArgs

    -- If we have arguments, read them as files and output them
    if (length args > 0) then catFileArray args

    -- Otherwise, output stdin to stdout
    else catHandle stdin

catFileArray :: [FilePath] -> IO ()
catFileArray files = do
    putStrLn $ "==> Number of files: " ++ (show $ length files)
    -- run `catFile` for each file passed in
    Monad.forM_ files catFile

catFile :: FilePath -> IO ()
catFile f = do
    putStrLn ("==> " ++ f)
    handle <- openFile f ReadMode
    catHandle handle

catHandle :: Handle -> IO ()
catHandle h = Monad.forever $ do
    eof <- IO.hIsEOF h
    if eof then do
        hClose h
        exitWith ExitSuccess
    else
        hGetLine h >>= putStrLn
```

I am running the code like this:

```
runghc cat.hs file1 file2
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your problem is that `exitWith` terminates the whole program. So, you cannot really use `forever` to loop through the file, because obviously you don't want to run the function "forever", just until the end of the file. You can rewrite `catHandle` like this

```
catHandle :: Handle -> IO ()
catHandle h = do
    eof <- IO.hIsEOF h
    if eof then do
        hClose h
     else
        hGetLine h >>= putStrLn
        catHandle h
```

I.e. if we haven't reached EOF, we recurse and read another line.

However, this whole approach is overly complicated. You can write cat simply as

```
main = do
    files <- getArgs
    forM_ files $ \filename -> do
        contents <- readFile filename
        putStr contents
```

Because of lazy i/o, the whole file contents are not actually loaded into memory, but streamed into stdout.

If you are comfortable with the operators from `Control.Monad`, the whole program can be shortened down to

```
main = getArgs >>= mapM_ (readFile >=> putStr)
```

Comment: I switched the accepted answer to yours because you fixed my bug and also explained the lazy IO streaming.

Comment: "kleisli composition". I don't know any better (shorter) name for it.

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Monad.html#v:-62--61--62-

Comment: thanks, good to know the actual name so I can read up on it. I will probably just keep calling it "leftfish" and "rightfish" in my head.

Comment: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Pronunciation doesn't have `>=>` -- considering that Sam's comment has 3 upvotes, is that enough to justify adding it to the page as "rightfish"?

Comment: If  you want to make it also read from std in, like cat, you can change your one line program to: main = getArgs >>= (\args -> if null args then interact id else mapM_ (readFile >=> putStr) args)

Answer (score 17):

If you install the very helpful [`conduit` package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-0.5.2), you can do it this way:

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad
import Data.Conduit
import Data.Conduit.Binary
import System.Environment
import System.IO

main :: IO ()
main = do files <- getArgs
          forM_ files $ \filename -> do
            runResourceT $ sourceFile filename $$ sinkHandle stdout
```

This looks similar to shang's suggested simple solution, but using conduits and [`ByteString`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring-0.9.2.1) instead of lazy I/O and `String`.  Both of those are good things to learn to avoid: lazy I/O frees resources at unpredictable times; `String` has a lot of memory overhead.

Note that `ByteString` is intended to represent binary data, not text.  In this case we're just treating the files as uninterpreted sequences of bytes, so `ByteString` is fine to use.  If OTOH we were processing the file as *text*—counting characters, parsing, etc—we'd want to use [`Data.Text`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/text-0.11.2.2).

**EDIT:** You can also write it like this:

```
main :: IO ()
main = getArgs >>= catFiles

type Filename = String

catFiles :: [Filename] -> IO ()
catFiles files = runResourceT $ mapM_ sourceFile files $$ sinkHandle stdout
```

In the original, `sourceFile filename` creates a `Source` that reads from the named file; and we use `forM_` on the outside to loop over each argument and run the `ResourceT` computation over each filename.

However in Conduit you can use monadic `>>` to concatenate sources; `source1 >> source2` is a source that produces the elements of `source1` until it's done, then produces those of `source2`.  So in this second example, `mapM_ sourceFile files` is equivalent to `sourceFile file0 >> ... >> sourceFile filen`—a `Source` that concatenates all of the sources.

**EDIT 2:** And following Dan Burton's suggestion in the comment to this answer:

```
module Main where

import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.IO.Class
import Data.ByteString
import Data.Conduit
import Data.Conduit.Binary
import System.Environment
import System.IO

main :: IO ()
main = runResourceT $ sourceArgs $= readFileConduit $$ sinkHandle stdout

-- | A Source that generates the result of getArgs.
sourceArgs :: MonadIO m => Source m String
sourceArgs = do args <- liftIO getArgs
                forM_ args yield

type Filename = String          

-- | A Conduit that takes filenames as input and produces the concatenated 
-- file contents as output.
readFileConduit :: MonadResource m => Conduit Filename m ByteString
readFileConduit = awaitForever sourceFile
```

In English, `sourceArgs $= readFileConduit` is a source that produces the contents of the files named by the command line arguments.

Comment: +1 an excellent testament to the simplicity and elegance that `conduit` has achieved. I wonder if a `getArgs`-esque Source would be of use. Then you could write `runResourceT $ sourceArgs $= readFileConduit $$ sinkHandle stdout` where `sourceArgs :: MonadIO m => Source m String` and `readFileConduit :: MonadResource m => Conduit FileName m ByteString`

Comment: @DanBurton: I'm still learning conduits, so I decided to try my hand at it—and succeeded within 10 minutes.  I'll edit the response to add that version.

Comment: This is not technically the answer to my question, but it's so informative that would consider it "required reading" for anyone with similar questions about Haskell.

Comment: @sacundim, would you mind adding a explanation of `sourceArgs` in the same way that you did for `catFiles`? Why do you have to do `liftIO`? What is `yield`? What package is `awaitForever` in? I couldn't compile the **EDIT 2** code. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Sam the truth of the matter is that the `conduit` library is a mere 7 months old, and has undergone several significant revisions since inception. As such, I wouldn't consider it "required reading" for Haskell newbs quite yet (especially since it might undergo even more significant changes), although `conduit` certainly does seem to have a bright future. Regarding yield and awaitForever, see [Data.Conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/conduit/latest/doc/html/Data-Conduit.html#v:awaitForever). Fair warning: the `conduit` type signatures can be quite daunting for a newcomer.

Comment: @DanBurton oh okay for some reason I was under the impression that Conduit was the "proper" way of doing it. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

`catHandle`, which is indirectly called from `catFileArray`, calls [`exitWith`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/System-Exit.html#v:exitWith) when it reaches the end of the first file. This terminates the program, and further files aren't read anymore.

You should instead just return normally from the `catHandle` function when the end of the file has been reached. This probably means you shouldn't do the reading `forever`.

Answer (score 5):

My first idea is this:

```
import System.Environment
import System.IO
import Control.Monad
main = getArgs >>= mapM_ (\name -> readFile name >>= putStr)
```

It doesn't really fail in unix-y way, and doesn't do stdin nor multibyte stuff, but it is "way more haskell" so I just wanted to share that. Hope it helps.

On the other hand, I guess it should handle large files easily without filling up memory, thanks to the fact that putStr can already empty the string during file reading.

Comment: Here's a simple version that reads from standard input and writes to standard output: main = interact id.